# Appium setting on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, automation, appium, ui-automation

I am facing a problem while setting up appium on Ubuntu. I am not sure whether appium is properly set or not?
After setting up I found this......

```
info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
info: Console LogLevel: debug
```

Is this the correct way to setup appium?
I followed the following guide to set up.
http://ubuntubegin.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-setup-appium-in-ubuntu.html

Please tell me is it right way or not.
Is there any graphical interface for appium on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A. If you are getting that output it means your appium install is successful and Appium is up and running on default port 4723. Next step is to connect to the server with Appium client.

B. In Ubuntu there are few GUI's to view logs such as gnome-system-log it's searchable and user-friendly, You can start System Log Viewer

> Click on System menu > Choose Administration > System Log

[How to view system log files in GUI](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/11/ubuntu-tips-how-to-view-system-log-files-in-gui/)
If you are expecting full graphical interface like Windows, so that's not available yet.

Answer (score 3):

Hello Friend the way you install and launch appium is right . There is no such GUI available for Appium in Ubuntu. GUI interface is available only for Windows and MAC OS

Still you have any issue then you may follow below mentioned steps to install appium on ubuntu.

Install Java on Ubuntu & Set Environment Variables for Java

Check that whether java is installed on the system or not by typing Java on command Prompt.

Install Android SDK on Ubuntu & Setup Path for Android SDK (ANDROID_HOME, Platform-tools and Tools)

Check that whether adb is installed on the system or not by typing adb on terminal.

[Steps to Setup Appium on Ubuntu](http://testingalert.com/steps-to-setup-appium-on-ubuntu/) (**Without using npm**) [**Recommended**]:-

**Step 1**. : Install ruby

Paste the below mentioned command on terminal and hit enter

sudo apt-get install build-essential curl git m4 ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev

**Step 2.** Install linuxbrew

Paste the below command at terminal and press enter

ruby -e “$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)”

**Step 3.** Setup path for brew

Type gedit.bashrc on terminal, copy & paste below commands into the .bashrc file

export PATH=”$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH”

export MANPATH=”$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH”

export INFOPATH=”$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH”

After Copy and Paste the above command save the file and close it.

**Step 4.** Install node

To install brew , paste the below commands one by one at terminal and press enter button

brew update

brew install node

brew link node

**Step 5.** Install Appium

To install Appium, type below mentioned command in terminal

npm install -g appium

npm install wd

**Step 6.** To start appium

Type “**appium**” into the terminal and press enter button.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue while setting up Appium on Ubuntu. 
No. there is no GUI for Appium server on Ubuntu. 
Your set up is correct and your Appium server started running.

Answer (score 0):

No. there is no GUI for Appium server on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Don't install node through linux brew,,directly take tar file from node website and install it works.

Answer (score 0):

Appium GUI is available for Ubuntu. Im using it and it works good.

[https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.6.2]
Download **appium-desktop-1.6.2-x86_64.AppImage**
and use command.

```
#chmod a+X appium-desktop-1.6.2-x86_64.AppImage
#./appium-desktop-1.6.2-x86_64.AppImage
```

It will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this thing on your console means you have done the right thing, but in Ubuntu, the way to open the ui for ubuntu is different

You have to install the Appimage file from the appium desktop and then

For Ubuntu/Linux you need to install the appium-desktop-1.10.0-x86_64.App-image.

After installing it we need to go to the properties -> permission -> allow it to open it with application

After doing this we need to double click on the icon and the Ubuntu window will be open

follow the steps in the link
**https://medium.com/@kaushik.shweta/appium-desktop-issue-in-linux-741604de29a2**

I hope you will be able to open the appium desktop Appimage and will able to use it

Answer (score 0):

GUI Appium for Ubuntu/Linux based system is available here: https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/download/v1.13.0/Appium-linux-1.13.0.AppImage

Answer (score -1):

info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723

above statement says that appium successfully started on ip: 0.0.0.0 and PORT: 4723 , 
You can configure different ports if you want while running the command

example: appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4726

above command will launch the appium as localhost and on port 4726